# How to append data to a json file on new line using Golang

Tags: json, go, io

```
type dataOP struct {

    Opcode_name string `json:"opcode_name"`
    ExeTime     int    `json:"exeTime"`
}

func main() {

    book := dataOP{Opcode_name: "ADD", ExeTime: 5}
    byteArray, err := json.Marshal(book)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    f, err := os.OpenFile("./data.json", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    n, err := io.WriteString(f, string(byteArray))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(n, err)
    }

}
```

I want to append data to a json file on new line using Golang. The above code appends the json object one after another, something like

`{"opcode_name":"ADD","exeTime":5}{"opcode_name":"ADD","exeTime":5}{"opcode_name":"ADD","exeTime":5}`

but i want to append these json objects in new line(json objects separated by new line).

```
{"opcode_name":"ADD","exeTime":5}
{"opcode_name":"ADD","exeTime":5}
{"opcode_name":"ADD","exeTime":5}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want each JSON object to start on a new line, simple write a newline after each object.

Also note that [`os.File`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File) has a [`File.Write()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Write) method to write a `[]byte`, so no need to convert it to `string`.

Also don't forget to close the file, preferably deferred:

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("./data.json", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer f.Close()

n, err := f.Write(byteArray)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(n, err)
}

if n, err = f.WriteString("\n"); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(n, err)
}
```

Also note that you could write the byte slice and a newline with a single call like this:

```
if _, err := fmt.Fprintf(f, "%s\n", byteArray); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```